# How to change the subtype of Chart from VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I create charts from some data:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlColumnStacked).Select
```

But on Excel there are different subtypes of the xlColumnStacked chart...

[image: d]

I need to show the second one, not the default one.

It has to be programmatically, not manually.

I tried to record the macro and see what does the change, but it doesn't record anything... I tried loading from Templates also but they don't work exactly like the one I need.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing you have to change .ChartTyp
for example:

```
 ActiveChart.ChartType = 52
```

Here is list of proper Value
https://bettersolutions.com/excel/charts/vba-chart-types.htm

If you want to switch x axis and y axis data try one of this:

```
ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlColumns

ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlRows
```

I hope I helped :)

Comment: The 52 chart is the default one I marked on the image. But I need to show the second one, which seems impossible to do by VBA

Comment: So you  Want to switch axis . One of this will by good for you `ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlColumns
ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlRows` I edited my answer and Added information about this

Comment: Ok, so the sub-charts are not accessible from VBA. I have to do the rotation by code after generating them... Thanks, I'll search how to do other sub-charts I need by code. Thanks, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

They both looked like stacked columns. VBA doesn't have chart subtypes, and controls the chart type using this syntax:

```
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClusteredStacked100
```

VBA's Object Browser shows you all of the possibilities.

Comment: So the chart I show on my image example (which is a subtype of xlColumnStacked) is not available from VBA? This means that VBA can't do all the actions we can manually do on Excel?

Comment: You'd cropped so much of the image, I didn't know what you were showing.. You want to specify `PlotBy` as either `xlRows` or `xlColumns`. You can do this when you set the chart's data with `ActiveChart.SetSourceData`, or using `ActiveChart.PlotBy`.

Comment: Ok, so the sub-charts are not accessible from VBA. I have to do the rotation by code after generating them... Thanks, I'll search how to do other sub-charts I need by code. Thanks, this helped a lot!

Comment: Okay, the different chart types include what you're calling subtypes. It's not Column chart with subtype Stacked Column, it's just type Stacked Column. Excel VBA is simpler than that, adjust your paradigm.